# Linux ext4 partition keeps converting all files to read-only mode

Tags: filesystems, ext4, deepin

I have installed Linux deepin os on my laptop which I have been using for the past 6 months now, the past two weeks,the computer slows down and when I save a file, I get and error `Read-only file system`. I have two ext4 partitions `/dev/sda1`(is bootable and has home partition) and `/dev/sda3`. It's affecting the two partitions.

I have been fixing this using this command as explained in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/a/422153/617811).

```
$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

Here is a screenshot of the output when I run the above command.

[image]

This fixes the problem but it happens at least twice a day, affecting my work significantly. I need to fix this issue permanently.

Comment: I'm assuming your ran this on unmounted partitions? How old is the disk?

Comment: Could also be dodgy RAM, with the in-memory filesystem structures getting failures. Running memtest just in case might be a good idea. (It's a startup option on most Linux install media I've seen.)

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes am running the command when unmounted. Am not sure how old the laptop is but can't be older than 4 years.

Answer (score 3):

The filesystem going readonly by itself is very likely the result of the filesystem driver encountering errors. You might see the `errors=remount-ro` option in the output of `mount`. It does that to protect the filesystem from further issues. (The alternatives are to continue and ignore the error, or to panic the system, see [`ext4(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html)). You should probably see something about the error in `dmesg`.

If it happens repeatedly, it's an indication of the hardware going bad. Check at least the disk and memory, and make backups while you can.

Comment: How do I get more information about the filesystem driver errors? Below is the output of dmesg

Comment: joe@jarvis  ~  dmesg | grep mount
[    5.306033] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.798523] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
[   45.261146] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   45.261199] partition /media/joe/Jarvis [8, 3] added, comm[1701]: mount

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hardware issue,

- Release the HDD from the current virtual machine.
- Create a new machine and attach that HDD to the new machine.

It works for me